# Saving program state when user invokes Ctrl-C

Tags: python

In python, when the user invokes Ctrl-C, what happens? Do I have the possibility to save the program state?

What about context-managers? Does the `__exit__()` section get executed?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised inside the main thread. So yes, you can handle it by catching it in try/except block and `__exit__()` sections are executed

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 4):

This is what the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module is for. You can register multiple exit handlers. You can see it at work by running this program and observing that a message is displayed:

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def exithandler():
    print("Exit trapped!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just mention [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) which is also a built in that can handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and many more signals such as `SIGHUP` etc.

```
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    # Do work
    # Thread cleanup
    # pickle program state
    # remove(pidfile) # as an example
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

This is just a example of a broad framework that can handle numerous signals.
[Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Sending_signals) of some of the signals you could catch.